# How to acquire full referenced document within one query?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

everyone!
I'm trying to get its referenced document when I query for an document using pymongo, the code is:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
comments = mongo_client.coll3.comments.find()
target = []
for comment in comments:
    relatived = mongo_client.coll3.users.find_one({'_id': comment.get('user')})
    comment['address'] = relatived.get('address')
    target.append(comment)
```

Since there are lots of comments, when I use "for comment in comments" loop,I have to search for db for many times which costs lots of time.

I wonder if it's possible to acquire the referenced document in the first query? thanks very much!

Comment: Umm [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). I know it's hard to find when https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+get+related only lists the manual page right up the top of the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use aggregation with `$lookup`.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)